# Rest Web Service: Anonymous and Authenticated users with token security

Tags: rest, security, authentication, spring-security, token

Am developing a mobile application that can be used Anonymously and When Authenticated.

For example anonymous Users can

- View list of competitions
- View User who is in the competition

When authenticated User can additionally

- Enter a competition
- Vote for a user who is in a competition
- Leave a comment about a user

With my endpoints looking something like the following

```
../API
  ../Competition
  ../Competition/Applicants

  ../Applicant
  ../Applicant/Vote
  ../Applicant/Review
```

How can token based authentication work for this design? 
If a request requires a token how can anonymous users also get access to resources that don't require authentication?

Answer (score 0):

you can configure it in spring security.A sample Xml configuration is below

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/PathForAnonymousUsers/**" access="permitAll" />
<!-- other configurations -->
</security:http>
```